# Google Ajax Crawlable Rewrite!!? _escaped_fragment_=

Tags: asp.net, ajax, hash

I have started down the ajax site path using hash bang

currently my urls look like:

```
http://www.domain.com/#!/index
http://www.domain.com/#!/studio
http://www.domain.com/#!/about
```

from reading google's docs: `http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/`

it looks like google will try and rewrite `http://www.domain.com/#!/`studio to

http://www.domain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=studio

I was wondering how I would get an IIS7 rewrite rule to redirect the escaped fragment to:

http://www.domain.com/studio    i.e. take the querystring arg and map it back to the root

the site is done in asp.net using umbraco so i have access to the rewrite config file from umbraco also!

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

@Giberno : It seems that you do not understand what pennylane is asking.

The whole reason pennylane is trying to redirect through IIS / web.config is so that the search engine robots are redirected to a static pre generated .htm/.html file.

The next gen robots, like googlebot, recognise a hashbang.

```
 hashbang = '#!' in 'http://example.com/#!/some/page/with/ajax/content'
```

When a robot detects this **hashbang** in the url it will convert the url to a _escaped_fragment_ query string url.

The example from above will be converted to:

```
'http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/some/page/with/ajax/content'
```

This because robots can not execute the javascrip. Yet you give a javascript solution? Enlighten me if I am wrong.

More info on [AJAX Applications and SEO](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html)

@pennylane : I am trying to do the same and I think I got it.

**Situation:**

- snapshots directory = 'http://example.com/snapshots/...'
- snapshot name = 'snapshot_{page}' where {page} = the pagename

  ex : 'http://example.com/snapshots/snapshot_contact.html'

When I browse to a snapshot, the snapshot is shown with a statuscode 200 OK.

I placed the following rewrite rule for the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>

                ... other rewrite rules ...

                <rule name="EscapedFragment" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="_escaped_fragment_=/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="snapshots/snapshot_{C:1}.html" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>  

                ... other rewrite rules ...

            </rules>
        </rewrite>

        ... other configs ...

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Redirect Rule Explenation:**

Match:

```
<match url="(.*)"/>
```

The rule is called on any url.

Condition:

```
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="_escaped_fragment_=/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)" />
```

If '_escaped_fragment_=/' is followed by a alphanumiriq string, with or without cased characters, underscore (_) or hyphen (-) ...

Rewrite Action:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="snapshots/snapshot_{C:1}.html" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Rewrite to the url without appending the query string.

Where {C:1} = the value of the '_escaped_fragment_' query string parameter

**Info Sources:**
I constructed this rewrite rule based on the following information:

- [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)
- [URL Rewrite Module 2.0 Configuration Reference : TRACKING CAPTURE GROUPS ACROSS CONDITIONS](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Tracking_capture_groups_across_conditions_)
- Testing patterns : [Testing Rewrite Rule Patterns](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns)

**Result:**

Browsing to:

```
'http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/test'
```

Should rewrite to:

```
GET 'http://example.com/snapshots/snapshot_test.html'
```

Testing the pattern {C:1} = 'test'.

**Testing:**

In my opinion the easiest way to test if your rewrite rule is working is to follow these steps:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>URL Rewrite Module Test</title>
</head>
<body>
      <h1>URL Rewrite Module Test Page</h1>
      <table>
            <tr>
                  <th>Server Variable</th>
                  <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <td>Original URL: </td>
                  <td><%= Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL"] %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <td>Final URL: </td>
                  <td><%= Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"] + "?" + Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"] %></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

- create a snapshot_test.aspx file under the same directory that contains the code from above.
- change the rewrite rule to rewrite to .aspx files instead of .html files
- And finaly enter the following url in your browser:

  'http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/test'

**[For more info on IIS rewrite testing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules)**

**In addition:**

Use the pretty url for the canonical url and the sitemap.xml.

```
Pretty url: 'http://example.com/#!/test'
Ugly url: 'http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

javascript code:

```
var hashchange;
function MyHash() {
    if(window.location.hash) {
       MyHash = window.location.hash.replace("#!/", "");
        $.get("process_page.asp?_escaped_fragment_=" + MyHash, function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    hashchange();
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    hashchange();
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="content"><!--#include file="process_page.asp"--></div>
```

and in process_page.asp:

do something to `GET` `_escaped_fragment_`

you can also reference:  http://www.gingerhost.com/ajax-demo/

BTW: I am not good at asp. my main language is php. but i did above code and do not need url rewrite